# .Net Winforms Databinding Parent Child

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, data-binding, parent-child

I would like create something using Windows Form to show Datas from an item and informations about childs (=Parent - Childs)

Something like this :
[image: Parent - Child Relation]

```
--For exemple, i have
--MyParent with properties
MyParent.Data1
MyParent.Data2
MyParent.Data3
MyParent.Childs()

--And for child
MyChild.Data1
MyChild.Data2
MyChild.Data3
```

So, in the first Combobox, I have my List of Items,
In the second one, i have my childs from the current selected Parent Item

I don't have any problem for bind parent, but that's another history for child !

```
Public bs As BindingSource = New BindingSource()
[...]
bs.DataSource = New BindingList(Of FopEtatFichier)(DateMyData))
TxtData1.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "Data1", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
TxtData2.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "Data2", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
TxtData3.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "Data3", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
ChkEtatSupprime.DataBindings.Add("Checked", bs, "EstSupprime", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
```

Am i obliged to create another one binding source for childs ? 
I made something really ugly :

```
Private Sub CbbChild_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CbbChild.SelectedValueChanged, CbbChild.DataSourceChanged

ChildData1.DataBindings.Clear()
ChildData2.DataBindings.Clear()
ChildData3.DataBindings.Clear()

ChildData1.DataBindings.Add("Text", CbbChild.SelectedItem, "ChildData1", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
ChildData2.DataBindings.Add("Checked", CbbChild.SelectedItem, "ChildData2", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
ChildData3.DataBindings.Add("Text", CbbChild.SelectedItem, "ChildData3", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
```

Is it possible to use the baove thing without always Clear / Add ?

(you can provide C# code if you prefere, no matter)

Thank You for your help !

Comment: You don't change bindings when selection changes.  The whole point of binding is you set it once and it's automatic after that.  Check this out: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?518065-Master-Detail-(Parent-Child)-Data-binding-(-NET-2-0-WinForms)

Comment: Yes, that's the problem, as i said, « really ugly » :(

Comment: Hmmm... I just realised that are using a `BindingList` as the underlying data source. Is that required? My suggestion would work with a `DataSet` because it contains `DataRelations`. For another data source, you would need to do more work.

Comment: And this could work, but it's not ... : ChildData1.DataBindings.Add("Text", CbbChild, "SelectedItem.ChildData1", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)

Comment: I know using dataset could work (i saw somes on StackOverflow) but i would like use classes i made :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example worked for me.  Create a WinForms app project and add `parentComboBox`, `parentTextBox`, `parentBindingSource`, `childComboBox`, `childTextBox` and `childBindingSource` to the form.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private parents As New List(Of Parent) From {New Parent With {.ParentId = 1, .Name = "Parent 1"},
                                                 New Parent With {.ParentId = 2, .Name = "Parent 2"},
                                                 New Parent With {.ParentId = 3, .Name = "Parent 3"}}
    Private children As New List(Of Child) From {New Child With {.ChildId = 1, .ParentId = 1, .Name = "Child 1"},
                                                 New Child With {.ChildId = 2, .ParentId = 2, .Name = "Child 2"},
                                                 New Child With {.ChildId = 3, .ParentId = 3, .Name = "Child 3"},
                                                 New Child With {.ChildId = 4, .ParentId = 1, .Name = "Child 4"},
                                                 New Child With {.ChildId = 5, .ParentId = 2, .Name = "Child 5"},
                                                 New Child With {.ChildId = 6, .ParentId = 3, .Name = "Child 6"},
                                                 New Child With {.ChildId = 7, .ParentId = 1, .Name = "Child 7"},
                                                 New Child With {.ChildId = 8, .ParentId = 2, .Name = "Child 8"},
                                                 New Child With {.ChildId = 9, .ParentId = 3, .Name = "Child 9"}}

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Use a dummy list to enable configuring the bindings without any data.
        childBindingSource.DataSource = New List(Of Child)

        With childComboBox
            .DisplayMember = "ChildId"
            .ValueMember = "ChildId"
            .DataSource = childBindingSource
        End With

        childTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", childBindingSource, "Name")

        parentBindingSource.DataSource = parents

        With parentComboBox
            .DisplayMember = "ParentId"
            .ValueMember = "ParentId"
            .DataSource = parentBindingSource
        End With

        parentTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", parentBindingSource, "Name")
    End Sub

    Private Sub parentComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles parentComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim parentId = CInt(parentComboBox.SelectedValue)

        'With this line, the first child will be selected after selecting a new parent.
        'Without this line, the child SelectedIndex will remain unchanged even though the SelectedItem has changed.
        childBindingSource.DataSource = New List(Of Child)

        childBindingSource.DataSource = children.Where(Function(child) child.ParentId = parentId)
    End Sub

End Class


Public Class Parent

    Public Property ParentId As Integer

    Public Property Name As String

End Class


Public Class Child

    Public Property ChildId As Integer

    Public Property ParentId As Integer

    Public Property Name As String

End Class
```